# remove items from cart in controller - magento2

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart, magento2.0.8

I need to remove all the items from cart, below method remove the items in `chenckout/cart/index` page but header minicart section still dispaly the **items** even after refresh page too.

I have try this logic in custom controller `app/code/Gworks/Cart/Controller/Items/Remove.php`

```
public function deleteQuoteItems(){
    $checkoutSession = $this->getCheckoutSession();
    $allItems = $checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();//returns all teh items in session
    foreach ($allItems as $item) {
        $itemId = $item->getItemId();//item id of particular item
        $quoteItem=$this->getItemModel()->load($itemId);//load particular item which you want to delete by his item id
        $quoteItem->delete();//deletes the item
    }
}
public function getCheckoutSession(){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();//instance of object manager 
    $checkoutSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');//checkout session
    return $checkoutSession;
}

public function getItemModel(){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();//instance of object manager
    $itemModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item');//Quote item model to load quote item
    return $itemModel;
}
```

after some search, I am trying to refresh minicart section using `<custom-module>/etc/sections.xml` but still the problem exist.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="checkout/cart/index">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

it confuse me, what I need to mention in action name. Actually I delete all item from  `checkout/cart/index` page and their delete logic in separate ajax call in my custom controller `gworks/items/remove`. I tried both but nothing happen.

can anyone give a neat way to entirely remove all items from cart?

**note:** I know object manager is not recommended, If it is worked after that I can change to dependency injection method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your custom controller should be:

```
namespace Gworks\Cart\Controller\Items;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;

class Remove extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $cart;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param CustomerCart $cart
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        CustomerCart $cart
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cart = $cart;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $allItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($allItems as $item) {
            $itemId = $item->getItemId();
            $this->cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        }

        $message = __(
            'You deleted all item from shopping cart.'
        );
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);

        $response = [
            'success' => true,
        ];

        $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($response)
        );
    }
}
```

Create sections.xml [Gworks/Cart/etc/frontend/sections.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="gworks/items/remove">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

Now add following code js code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '&lt;?php echo $block->getUrl('gworks/items/remove');?>',
    type: 'POST',
    showLoader: true,
    success: function (res) {
        if (res.messages) {
            $('[data-placeholder="messages"]').html(res.messages);
        }

        if (res.minicart) {
            $('[data-block="minicart"]').replaceWith(res.minicart);
            $('[data-block="minicart"]').trigger('contentUpdated');
        }
    }
});
```

Clear cache and delete var/generation/*

Comment: hi Sohel Where can i add this js code ?

Comment: @Pratik inside your phtml

Comment: what is contentUpdated? @SohelRana

Comment: @RohanHapani contentUpdated is magento custom event.

Comment: I removed cart product programmatically and product removed from cart but counter not proper working. can you give me any solution how to minicart refresh/reload?

Comment: @SohelRana Your code is working well. Could you tell me If I want to remove specific product then how can I do it.  Actually I have removed specific product successfully it also removes from cart too. but my cart number are not properly update. I have added question on this url: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258718/how-to-update-minicart-count-after-remove-product-programatically-on-cart-page/258721?noredirect=1#comment364328_258721

Comment: @SohelRana, I need to remove item by matching product id, if exist in quote, is like that possbile? tried here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265692/delete-and-add-product-again-from-cart-in-magento-2, but its not working

Comment: @Jaimin Could you help me with removing the specific product from the cart?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this also can be worked out.

In your phtml file, button tag like this

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data'); ?>

<button id="clear-cart" class="action tocart primary" title="<?php echo __('Clear Cart') ?>" ><?php echo __('Clear Cart') ?></button>
```

and javascript function for onclick, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("clear-cart").onclick = function () {
            location.href = '<?php echo $_helper->getClearCartUrl(); ?>';
        };
    </script>
```

As I have called helper function on click location, we need to create helper function in any of our helper class. Like this,

```
public function getClearCartUrl(){
        $checkoutSession = $this->getCheckoutSession();
        $quoteId = $checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();
        $quoteItem = $this->getQuoteModel()->load($quoteId);
        $quoteItem->delete();
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() .'checkout/cart/' ;  //Need to load $this->storeManager in construct method to get Base URL
    }

    public function getCheckoutSession(){
        $checkoutSession = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');//checkout session
        return $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function getQuoteModel(){
        $quoteModel = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');//Quote item model to load quote
        return $quoteModel;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

my code :

```
checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cart = $cart;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

public function execute()
{     
    $allItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($allItems as $item) {
        $itemId = $item->getItemId();
        $this->cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();
    }
    $this->cart->truncate()->save();
    $message = __(
        'You deleted all item from shopping cart.'
    );
    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $redirect = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
    $redirect->setRedirect('/');
     

    return $redirect;
    
}

}
js code-->

    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function ($, alertt, confirmation,customerData) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.cp-action-accept').parents('aside').addClass('confirm');
            $('#empty_cart_button_cart').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                confirmation({
                    title: '',
                    content: 'Are you sure to remove products from cart ?',
                    actions: {
                        confirm: function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'getUrl('clearcheckout/item/removeitem');?>',
                                type: 'POST',
                                showLoader: true,
                                success:function(response){
                                    var sections = ['cart'];
                                    customerData.invalidate(sections);
                                    window.location.reload();
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        cancel: function () {
                        }
                    },
                    buttons: [
                    {
                            text: $.mage.__('Cancel'),
                            class: 'action secondary action-dismiss',
                            /**
                             * Click handler.
                             */
                            click: function (event) {
                                this.closeModal(event);
                            }
                        },
                    {
                        text: $.mage.__('OK'),
                        class: 'action secondary cp-action-accept',
                        /**
                         * Click handler.
                         */
                        
                    }    
                    ]
                });
            });
        });
    });
```