# magento 2 remove mini cart item page reload?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, ajax, mini-cart

How can I reload the page when I remove mini cart item ?
I know it's `Magento 2` bug.

On the checkout cart page there are many products In mini cart as well as In checkout cart page when I remove In mini cart, content not updated and I know it's a big thing to update checkout cart page content using Ajax so I am thinking about when customer remove item from cart I need to reload the page.

Comment: try this it works for me http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141334/36463

Comment: You can put javascript page reload `window.location.reload();` after remove ajax completes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed issue in all checkout page magento 2

> app/design/frontend/Magento/yourtheme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/sidebar.js

**=> put the comment code after comple function**

```
.done(function (response) {
    var msg;
    if (response.success) {
        callback.call(this, elem, response);
       /** **page reload code */
        if(this.options.url.remove == url && window.location.href.indexOf("checkout") > -1){
            window.location.reload(true);
        }**
        /** page reload code */
    } else {
        msg = response['error_message'];

        if (msg) {
            alert({
                content: msg
            });
        }
    }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any module in `/app/code`
Then inside that module crate or edit a file under `Namespace/Your module/etc/frontend/sections.xml`.

And write and inside This file:

```
<action name="checkout/sidebar/removeItem">
<section name="cart"/>
</action>
```

This should be written under valid configuration declaration you can see how to write this in module-checkout under vendor/magento.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix for this issue.

Copy the file

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js

to

your_theme_path/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/minicart.js

In the initialize function

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("checkout/cart") > -1) {
         location.reload();
     }
```

Add this code in the contentLoading function like this

```
$('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentLoading', function (event) {
            addToCartCalls++;
            self.isLoading(true);
                $('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentUpdated', function ()  {
                    $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("open");       
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $('[data-block="minicart"]').find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("close");
                }, 4000);
            });
            if(window.location.href.indexOf("checkout/cart") > -1) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
```