# How i Stop "Add to cart" redirect "checkout/cart/" in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I had done some changes from this [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157890/magento-2-remove-mini-cart-item-page-reload) then products can not add to cart that redirect to checkout/cart in magento 2.I removed sections.xml file and excute setup:static-content:deploy but problem can not solve.how i stop "add cart" TO "checkout/cart/" and I want "add product" to "cart"

Comment: are you want to keep product page after add to cart?

Comment: yeah i done some changes from above link then it cant work

Answer (score 2):

Go to backend,
**Stores -> Configuration ->Sales -> Checkout**

```
Shopping Cart -> After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart
```

- Set **No**
- Save the Configuration Page
- Clear cache.

Comment: i do that but i cant "save config" thats redirect to dashboard

Comment: just remove broswer cache and clear var folder from root.

Comment: if not working run deployment command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: ok i try that and call you thanks for response

Comment: i removed var/* files and excuted  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy but no change.

Answer (score 0):

System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout

After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart

Set to No

Comment: i do that but i cant "save config" thats redirect to dashboard

Comment: This sounds like one of your extensions are conflicting, have you tried redeploying and deleting the cache if that doesnt work i would suggest  checking the exception logs also system logs if no errors then going through and disabling your modules 1 by 1 to find the issue

Comment: yes i have three extensions."system logs" location in var folder?

Comment: if you open your system.log file and post the errors here can possibly find a solution for you

Comment: [access_compat:error] [pid 3244:tid 836] [client ::1:53041] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: G:/wamp/www/magento_store/app/etc/config.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this package I created sometime ago:

https://packagist.org/packages/gustavoulyssea/magento-redirect-checkout

Before adding via composer take a look at the code. If that´s exactly what you need simply use composer. If not feel free to copy my code and make your own changes.

If you have any question please let me know !

Answer (score 0):

you should check console , there must be some js files which are missing

try to copy them from local magento to your web directories and you will get result.