# How to update Minicart count after remove product Programatically on cart page

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

**I have created automatically remove product with a specific ID Functionality.**
So when the customer removes any product my specific ID product will be automatically removed.

I have done below code

**Path:** `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Delete.php`

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

class Delete extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart
{
    /**
     * Delete shopping cart item action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            try {
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');                 
                // retrieve quote items collection
                $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();                 
                // get array of all items what can be display directly
                $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();                 
                // retrieve quote items array
                $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
                $cartid = "";
                foreach($items as $item)
                {
                    if($item->getProductId() == 110009)
                    {
                        $cartid = $item->getItemId();        
                    }

                }
                $this->cart->removeItem($id)->save();
                if($cartid != "")
                {
                    $this->cart->removeItem($cartid)->save();
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t remove the item.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            }
        }
        $defaultUrl = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::class)->getUrl('*/*');
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($defaultUrl));
    }
}
```

**My Issue:**

When the customer removes any product my specific ID product will be automatically removed but my mini cart count is only removed only one product.

**For Instance:** There is 3 product in cart including my specific ID product. Now if Customer removes one of the product it removes that product and my specified ID product too. But my cart count will deduct only 1 product.

**So Expected result of Minicart should be 1 but it shows 2.**

Could anyone help me that how can I set proper count in minicart?

Comment: Did you create sections.xml file?

Comment: I am doing by override delete controller. Path:html/demo/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Delete.php

Comment: I don't have my custom controller so I don't think I need to create sections.xml because it used default magento sections.xml file.

Answer (score 3):

**I have solved Issue. Below is my code.**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

class Delete extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart
{
    /**
     * Delete shopping cart item action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }

        $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            try {
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');                 
                // retrieve quote items collection
                $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();                 
                // get array of all items what can be display directly
                $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();                 
                // retrieve quote items array
                $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
                $cartid = "";
                foreach($items as $item)
                {
                    if($item->getProductId() == 110009)
                    {
                        $cartid = $item->getItemId();        
                    }

                }
                $this->cart->removeItem($id);
                if($cartid != "")
                {
                    $this->cart->removeItem($cartid)->save();
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t remove the item.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            }
        }
        $defaultUrl = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::class)->getUrl('*/*');
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl($defaultUrl));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not use objectManager in vendor folder or your custom module.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a mixin to override it in your own theme:

```
define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',],function ($,customerData) {
return function(originalWidget) {

    $.widget('mage.sidebar', $.mage.sidebar, {

        _removeItemAfter: function (elem) {
            var productData = customerData.get('cart')().items.filter(function (item) {
                if(Number(elem.data('cart-item')) === Number(item['item_id'])) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            $(document).trigger('ajax:removeFromCart', productData[0]['product_sku']);
        },
    });

    return $.mage.sidebar;
}});
```

in the requirejs-config you can add

```
var config = {
"config": {
    "mixins": {
        "Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar-mixin': true
        }
    }
}};
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you tell me where I need to put this code? Could you provide me with a path?

Comment: There are two way:
1) Create your own module and use mixins
2) Override the file "vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\sidebar.js" in your own theme.

Comment: I have tried your code Amit but it is not updated cart quantity. I have get one url in which it removes all products from cart and it works but when I try to remove specific product on that code it gives same issue. Could you help me with this. URL: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141314/remove-items-from-cart-in-controller-magento2/141334

Comment: @Jaimin, for this we need to debug the code.